NAudio stream WasapiLoopbackCapture
I am trying to write a simple remote speaker audio capture app using NAudio.
There is a winforms client app that captures the audio and sends it with HttpRequests to a winforms server app.
I have tried many things without success. The best I have managed is to get white noise in the receiving end.
Client Side. I want to continuously capture and send the audio. Tried also with WaveFileWriter, stoping the recording each time and restarting and writer.Position > capture.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * some seconds.
public MainForm()
 {
     InitializeComponent();

     url = "http://192.168.200.200:";

     currentPort = "80";

     CaptureAudio();
 }

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

string url;

string currentPort;

WasapiCapture capture;

private void CaptureAudio()
{
    capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();

    capture.DataAvailable += async (s, e) =>
    {
        try
        {
            using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            memoryStream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);

            using var content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());

            content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/wav");

            using var response = await client.PostAsync($"{url}{currentPort}/", content);
        }
        catch { }
    };

    capture.StartRecording();
}

And on the Server Side. Tried also BufferedWaveProvider and waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing
private async Task StartHttpListener()
{
    var listener = new HttpListener();

    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:80/");

    listener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var context = await listener.GetContextAsync();

            Task.Run(() => HandleRequest(context));
        }
        catch { }
    }
}

 private async Task HandleRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
 {
     if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST" && context.Request.ContentType == "audio/wav")
     {
         var waveOut = new WaveOutEvent();

         var waveStream = new RawSourceWaveStream(context.Request.InputStream, new WaveFormat(48000, 2));

         waveOut.Init(waveStream );

         waveOut.Play();

         context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

         await context.Response.OutputStream.WriteAsync(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 0);

         context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
     }
 }

Please excuse my ignorance on the subject but I can't grasp it...
